# Использование document.getElementsByClassName() С переменными

Tags: javascript, html, css, методы

Имеется выражение вида:

```
collection = document.getElementsByClassName('client name');
```

В котором собирается коллекция элементов HTML, где каждый элемент содержит в себе одновременно классы "client" и "name". При попытке заменить строку "client name" на 2 соответствующие переменные clientVariable и nameVariable возникают проблемы:

Вариант с пробелом

```
collection = document.getElementsByClassName(сlientVariable nameVariable);
```

либо с точкой с запятой

```
collection = document.getElementsByClassName(clientVariable; nameVariable);
```

Выдает

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Вариант с запятой

```
collection = document.getElementsByClassName(clientVariable, nameVariable);
```

Работает, но похоже принимает только clientVariable и игнорирует nameVariable.

Как мне заставить работать метод getElementsByClassName с несколькими переменными?

Comment: Вы наверное это имеете ввиду:

collection = document.getElementsByClassName(clientVariable + ' ' + nameVariable);

Вы должны использовать конкатенацию двух своих строковых переменных, но getElementsByClassName не позволит сделать то что вы хотите, используйте  document.querySelectorAll